# Batch - redirect program output to current console

Tags: batch-file

Lets say this is **test.bat**

```
START cmd /c "D:\myprogram.exe" arg0 arg1 ^>out.txt

pause
```

This works fine, but I want to show the output of myprogram.exe inside the test.bat console, instead of creating a text file for it. The problem is that myprogram.exe creates a new console, finishes and closes the console window before I can see the output and so far I can only write it to a text file. How can I redirect the output to test.bat's console window instead?

Comment: Why are you using `START cmd  /c` in the batch file?

Comment: Have you tried using just `@"D:\myprogram.exe" arg0 arg1`?

Comment: Instead of using `START` just reference the program directly in your script, unless there is some reason you want it to run in some separate window?

Comment: I sure would like to see the resource on the web that told you to use `START CMD /C`.

Answer (score 1):

According to the comments, it appears that the following is all I needed:

```
@"D:\myprogram.exe" arg0 arg1
```

Answer (score 0):

From help

```
C:\WINDOWS\system32>start /?
Starts a separate window to run a specified program or command.

…

command/program
            If it is an internal cmd command or a batch file then
            the command processor is run with the /K switch to cmd.exe.
            This means that the window will remain after the command
            has been run.

            If it is not an internal cmd command or batch file then
            it is a program and will run as either a windowed application
            or a console application.

parameters  These are the parameters passed to the command/program.
```

So to recap. `Start` is for starting programs **in unusual ways**.