# Windows batch redirect output to console

Tags: batch-file, cmd, io-redirection, ibm-doors

The summary of this question is I have a command I'm running in batch, `Some.exe args` but it is not outputting to the console. It does however output to a text file if used like `Some.exe args > test.txt`. I've tried stuff like `@Some.exe args` and `Some.exe args > CON` to get it to output to the console, but neither seems to work.

Are there any other approaches which might work?

---

This follows on from a previous question I asked [DOORS make console the interactive window](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72263903/doors-make-console-the-interactive-window).

I'm calling a program called DOORS through a batch script. It runs a simple script, `hello.dxl` that looks like

```
cout << "Hello world"
```

The batch script, `Run.bat` looks like

```
"C:\Program Files\IBM\Rational\DOORS\9.6\bin\doors.exe" -u test -pass testPass -b hello.dxl
```

When this is run, no output appears on the screen and there are no popup windows or anything (if `hello.dxl` said `print("Hello World")` an interactive window would pop-up, but not with `cout`)

If I add `> test.txt` to the end of the command

```
"C:\Program Files\IBM\Rational\DOORS\9.6\bin\doors.exe" -u test -pass testPass -b hello.dxl > test.txt
```

It outputs the `Hello World` to `test.txt` successfully. Something I noticed is when using `print("Hello World")` there was no output sent to the `test.txt` file and an interactive window popped up so it looks like `cout` is the way to go.

So I though the output might just not be being output anywhere, so I tried adding `> CON` instead to try to force it to go to the console.

```
"C:\Program Files\IBM\Rational\DOORS\9.6\bin\doors.exe" -u test -pass testPass -b hello.dxl > CON
```

But that still resulted in a blank output.

I also tried adding an `@`, before the command, as suggested in this [Batch - redirect program output to current console](https://stackoverflow.com/q/64248192/4601149), like

```
@"C:\Program Files\IBM\Rational\DOORS\9.6\bin\doors.exe" -u test -pass testPass -b hello.dxl
```

or

```
@"C:\Program Files\IBM\Rational\DOORS\9.6\bin\doors.exe" -u test -pass testPass -b hello.dxl > CON
```

But no luck there either

I would have tried to reproduce this issue without DOORS but I don't know what is causing it in the first place.

---

Edit: I'm not really looking to use `> test.txt & type test.txt` as that is the current workaround I am using. But ideally I don't want it outputting to a text file

Comment: looks like a version of an old trick in ancient windows programs that (for some kind of compatibility with their previous MSDOS versions) checked for stdout being redirected to decide to either behave as a CLI program or as a GUI.

Comment: @PA. Would that mean in this case there is no way to achieve what I want or is that just the difference between the cout and print statements?

Comment: it would be tricky. If I am right, or near, the target program would put a lot of effort on recognizing where the stdout finally ends, so that would be hard to fool

Comment: @PA. Where do you think the stdout is currently ending up though? It's strange when I run the command it just has no output in the console

Comment: probably the program has some internal logic to prevent output to stdout

Comment: in my imagination, a possible dessign pattern for a dual CLI/GUI program would be to first test if stdout is redirected, if it is, outputs to stdout; if it is not, opens a window for output.

Comment: @PA. Ah okay, that's annoying but thanks for an idea of what might be happening

Comment: @PA. Managed to fool it, ish :)

Comment: What happens if you use piping, e.g.: Some.exe args | findstr /r /c:.*   ?

Comment: @Konrad I think that is powershell stuff?

Comment: @Dan. This is common cmd batch. My question was to see what happens when you redirect the output to a pipe instead of to a file. The findstr stuff is only to have a (useless) pipe that lets pass everything. You could also use more or head and so on. With some programs this may work.

Comment: @Konrad My bad. I've just come back to this and your suggestion seems to be the only reliable way to achieve close enough to what I want. Am I correct in thinking this will only output at the end of the operation and not in real time? It would be ideal to get the output as it happens but if this is the only way I don't mind

Comment: @Konrad Also it would be great if you could leave your comment as an answer so I can mark the problem as solved

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is more a workaround.
The idea is to a use a pipe program in order to redirect the output of the Windows program to the console:

```
SomeWinProg SomeArgs 2>>&1 | SomePipeProg PipeProgArgs
```

As a pipe program you may use a program that passes throug everything, like:

```
SomeWinProg SomeArgs 2>>&1 | findstr /r "/c:.*"
```

If this works or not depends on the Windows program.

Concerning the timing:
There may be some trouble when you have a long time running Windows program which produces sporadic output or when the output is done always to the same line (no line feeds, only carriage returns) and you want to have the output in real time.
In these cacses Windows programs like **findstr** or **find** are a little bit weak.
On github there is an implementation of **[mtee](https://github.com/ritchielawrence/mtee)** thats fits better:

```
SomeWinProg SomeArgs 2>>&1 | mtee nul
```

Comment: Thanks for this, really like the mtee suggestion and have added it to the script

Answer (score 2):

Turns out this approach has limited functionality, as soon as I tried opening a module, it made the interactive window pop up and no output was visible in the interactive window or the the console window

This is not an issue with the `> test.txt & type test.txt` workaround

---

Based on [@PA.'s](https://stackoverflow.com/users/30447/pa) suggestion that the program is somehow preventing output to stdout but not if it was redirected, so I wrote a small C# console app which looks like

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

using Process process = new();
process.EnableRaisingEvents = true;
process.ErrorDataReceived += ErrOut;
process.OutputDataReceived += StdOut;
process.StartInfo.FileName = args[0].Trim();
process.StartInfo.Arguments = args[1].Trim();
process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
process.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
process.Start();
process.BeginErrorReadLine();
process.BeginOutputReadLine();
process.WaitForExit();

static void ErrOut(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs dataReceivedEventArgs)
{
    if (dataReceivedEventArgs.Data != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(dataReceivedEventArgs.Data);
    }
}

static void StdOut(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs dataReceivedEventArgs)
{
    if (dataReceivedEventArgs.Data != null)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(dataReceivedEventArgs.Data);
    }
}
```

I then exported this to a single exe using the command

```
dotnet publish /p:DebugType=None /p:DebugSymbols=false /p:PublishReadyToRun=true /p:PublishSingleFile=true /p:PublishReadyToRunShowWarnings=true /p:PublishTrimmed=false /p:IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract=true /p:IncludeAllContentForSelfExtract=true "RedirectOutput.csproj" -o "." -c release
```

which I added then just added the folder with that exe in to my path environment variable.

Now I can just do

```
RedirectOutput "C:\Program Files\IBM\Rational\DOORS\9.6\bin\doors.exe" "-u test -pass testPass -b hello.dxl"
```

and I get the desired output